# Inno Setup - How can I put a version number on the bottom left corner of welcome page

Tags: inno-setup

I want to display a version number on bottom left corner of installer Welcome page, just like shown in this image. But I am not sure how to customize launch page. Can anyone suggest how to do this using Inno Setup script?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new [`TNewStaticText` label](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewStaticText) in the [`InitializeWizard` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeWizard):

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  VersionLabel: TNewStaticText;
begin
  VersionLabel := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  VersionLabel.Caption := Format('Version: %s', ['{#SetupSetting("AppVersion")}']);
  VersionLabel.Parent := WizardForm;
  VersionLabel.Left := ScaleX(16);
  VersionLabel.Top :=
    WizardForm.BackButton.Top +
    (WizardForm.BackButton.Height div 2) -
    (VersionLabel.Height div 2);
  // Needed for WizardStyle=modern
  VersionLabel.Anchors := [akLeft, akBottom];
end;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for...Thank you very much.